# What's wrong in my solution to $\int \frac{1}{(3x - 2)^2} dx$?

Tags: integration

I'm solving it this way:

$$u = 3x - 2\\
\frac{du}{3} = dx$$

$$\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{u^2} du \\
= \frac{1}{3} \frac{3}{u^3} + C$$

Comment: $\int{1\over u^2}\,du=\int u^{-2}\,du=-u^{-1}+C$.

Comment: $D f \neq \int f$

Comment: Thank you @DavidMitra. If you could promote your comment to an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David has pointed out, $$\int\frac{1}{u^2}\mathop{du}=-u^{-1}+C$$